# Background Thread while loop only runs once

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a client (windows.forms) to connect to a server (not my server), and have the client continuously receive data from the server.

At first I was hoping there would be some kind of event that would be raised when the server attempted to send data to the client (so that I can just take that data and present it in my client.) But I haven't found any such thing yet.

Instead I tried creating a loop that is supposed to take data from the server and present it in my client for as long as the client is connected to the server. But this only runs once, for some reason. (Maybe the server thinks I'm some kind of DDOS attacker and shuts down the connection?)

Here's my code:

```
    private void connectToServer() {
        client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
        nwStream = client.GetStream();

        new Thread(() => {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            while (client.Connected) {
                byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                updateOutputWindow(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    private int i = 0;

    private void updateOutputWindow(string text) {
        if (InvokeRequired) {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                updateOutputWindow(text);
            }));
        }
        else {
            rtb_outputWindow.AppendText(text);
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I have added the 'int i' just to see if the method updateOutputWindow gets called several times or not.
The result is a MessageBox that shows "0", and then nothing more. (If the loop would run more times it would show "1", "2", "3", "4", etc..)

I know it connects to the server because the server sends me a "welcome screen" that shows up as intended. (After that nothing happens.)

Comment: How much data do you expect? It seems you expect the connection to close when all data is received, and if you have less data than `client.ReceivedBufferSize', that means all data gets there in one go.

Comment: Do you know for sure the server sends more data after "welcome"? How would this be triggered? Put some Console.WriteLine messages inside the thread to see what happens. And maybe some exception handling.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488562/tcp-connection-keep-alive help?

Comment: @oerkelens It's hard to say. The server I'm connecting to is actually a game. So it depends on how long you play, how much data you get. I'm guessing the answer is "a lot".

Comment: @JeffRSon: I know for sure that the server sends more data once the client has responded (either by logging in or creating a new account.) So the server sits idly and waits for input after the welcome screen. I have no idea how this  would be triggered.

Comment: @mjwills: I have looked at that solution before, but I haven't figured out how it works yes. So I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I am posting it here in case someone else needs it in the future. (It might also be improved upon.) The code looks like this:

```
    private void connectToServer() {
        client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
        nwStream = client.GetStream();

        writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        connected = true;

        getDataFromServer();

        if (getDataTimer == null) {
            getDataTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            getDataTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            getDataTimer.Interval = 1000;
            getDataTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        if (connected) {
            getDataFromServer();
        }
    }

    private void getDataFromServer() {
        new Thread(() => {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            updateOutputWindow(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
        }).Start();
    }

    private void updateOutputWindow(string text) {
        if (InvokeRequired) {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                updateOutputWindow(text);
            }));
        }
        else {
            rtb_outputWindow.AppendText("\n" + text);
        }
    }
```

The biggest change was to make the code in getDataFromServer run in a background thread. Not sure if creating new background threads like that is a good idea, though. Will the garbage collector take care of it?